# Table with expanding div overlaps with next row?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create table where each `<td>` contains an div that can expand but the problem is table row doesn't expand with the div. Below is my example code:

```js
document.querySelector('.expand').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let additionalInfo = document.querySelector('.additional-info');
  if (additionalInfo.style.display === 'none') {
    additionalInfo.style.display = "block";
    additionalInfo.style.maxHeight = additionalInfo.scrollHeight + "px";
  } else {
    additionalInfo.style.display = "none";
    additionalInfo.style.maxHeight = 0 + "px";
  }
});
```

```css
.main-info {
  width: 650px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.additional-info {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="text"></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="main-info">
            <div class="expand">Expand</div>
            Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
            <div class="additional-info">
              Some additional Information!<br> Some additional Information!<br> Some additional Information!<br> Some additional Information!<br> Some additional Information!<br> Some additional Information!<br> Some additional Information!<br> Some additional
              Information!<br> Some additional Information!
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="main-info">
            <div class="expand">Expand</div>
            Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
            <div class="additional-info">
              Some additional Information!<br> Some additional Information!<br> Some additional Information!<br> Some additional Information!<br> Some additional Information!<br> Some additional Information!<br> Some additional Information!<br> Some additional
              Information!<br> Some additional Information!
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>


    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the td element:

```
<td>
    <div class="main-info">
        <div class="expand">Expand</div>
        Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
    <div class="additional-info">
        Some additional Information!<br>
        Some additional Information!<br>
        Some additional Information!<br>
        Some additional Information!<br>
        Some additional Information!<br>
        Some additional Information!<br>
        Some additional Information!<br>
        Some additional Information!<br>
        Some additional Information!
    </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Basically, when the `additional-info` div becomes visibles, it overlaps with the contents of the next row. I noticed that if the `additional-info` div is not part of `main-info` but added as its own element inside the td, the row expands nicely:

```
<td>
    <div class="main-info">
        <div class="expand">Expand</div>
        Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
    </div>

    <!-- additional-info is separate from main-info -->
    <div class="additional-info">
        Some additional Information!<br>
        Some additional Information!<br>
        Some additional Information!<br>
        Some additional Information!<br>
        Some additional Information!<br>
        Some additional Information!<br>
        Some additional Information!<br>
        Some additional Information!<br>
        Some additional Information!
    </div>
</td>
```

Is there a way to get this same behavior but keep the `additional-info` div as part of the `main-info` div? I don't want to use additional libraries like JQuery, just vanilla JS along with HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change class main-info from

```
.main-info {
    width: 650px;
    height: 150px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

to

```
.main-info {
    width: 650px;
    min-height: 150px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

and the col will expand nicely